# Hibernate: DAO and entity in the case of a table with only IDs

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entity, dao

I have the following schema with three simple tables:

```
STUDENTS: id, name, lastname
HOBBY: id, hobby_name
HOBBY_STUDENT: id_hobby, id_student
```

I have a server with Hibernate ans Spring running.

One JSP page executes CRUD operations on STUDENT and an other on HOBBY.

This was quite easy and I just needed an entity similar to this:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="STUDENT")
  public class Student {

        @Id
        @Column(name="ID")
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name="NAME")
        private String name;

        @Column(name="LASTNAME")
        private String lastName;

        // Getters and setters here
  }
```

Now I need to create a page to manage HOBBY_STUDENT. The problem is that I should't show in the JSP page the IDs, but the respective values instead (that is the hobbyes associated to the students and the student information).

In order to do that, how should I write my Entity and my DAO? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: A set of hobbies should be maintained in `Student` class. This set will serve as association between `Student` and `Hobby`.

Answer (score 0):

As Santosh Pingale said : A set of hobbies should be maintained in Student class.

So your entity Student should become someting like this :

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="STUDENT")
  public class Student {

        @OneToMany
        @JoinTable(name="student_hobbies", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="student_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="hobby_id"))
        private Collection<Hooby> hobbies;

        @Id
        @Column(name="ID")
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name="NAME")
        private String name;

        @Column(name="LASTNAME")
        private String lastName;

        // Getters and setters here
  }
```